# Reference for Donaldson's paper on Lefschetz pencils

Tags: reference-request

I am studying Donaldson's paper "LEFSCHETZ PENCILS ON SYMPLECTIC
MANIFOLDS". Since the paper is a famous paper I believe there must be lecture notes / books which discuss this paper.  I will be extremely grateful if anyone can give reference of lecture notes / books which contain the content of the paper.